# I need a more efficient way to handle multiple indexes in numerical order

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

I am trying to make a bot that can automatically message the people in my DM's. I got it to message the first person, GO BACK, and message the second person by using this code here.

```
By path3 = By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='1']"); 
driver.findElement(path3).click(); 

By path4 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Message…']");
driver.findElement(path4).sendKeys("Hello");

 driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/row_thread_composer_button_send")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/action_bar_button_back")).click();

By path5 = By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='2']"); 
driver.findElement(path5).click();

By path6 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Message…']");
driver.findElement(path6).sendKeys("Hello");

driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/row_thread_composer_button_send")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/action_bar_button_back")).click();
```

But this is not efficient because if I use this method, i'd have to make a new line for every new index.

Does anybody know how to re-write this into a more efficient style?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop and the actual number of contacts. Here I assumed it was a range()

```
contacts = range(10)
for x in contacts:
    By path3 = By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='{0}']".format(x);
    driver.findElement(path3).click();

    By path4 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Message…']");
    driver.findElement(path4).sendKeys("Hello");

    driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/row_thread_composer_button_send")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/action_bar_button_back")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public void sendMsg() {

    List<MobileElement> paths = (List<MobileElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.LinearLayout']"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

      for (MobileElement path : paths) 
       {
        By path4 = By.xpath("//*[@text='Message…']");
        driver.findElement(path4).sendKeys("Hello");
         driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/row_thread_composer_button_send")).click();
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/action_bar_button_back"))));
         driver.findElement(By.id("com.instagram.android:id/action_bar_button_back")).click();


    }

}
```